# How to implement dynamic menu using typescript in xaml.

Tags: javascript, jquery, xaml, mvvm, typescript

I want to implement dynamic menu using typescript in xaml. I have a table with 5 columns, category, technologyfamily, area, sub area, activity. This 5 columns must be displayed in the form of menu. category is the parent and technologyfamily is the child of category and technologyfamily is parent of area and so on.

This menu must be designed in XAML using typescript/Javascript.
Can any one help me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you building a Windows 10 application? XAML is a Windows tech.

Answer (score 0):

> using typescript in xaml.

XAML is a .Net technology that needs a .Net runtime.  TypeScript compiles to JavaScript and needs a JavaScript virtual machine.

You cannot easily use TypeScript in Xaml and no such solution exists out there at the moment

## More

There is however TSX + React support in TypeScript that might grab your attention : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/jsx/tsx.html